# NoClassDefFound - org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, war

I have an `ear` file, inside `ear` file I have the `war` file. Its based on Spring 2.5.6 and jdk 1.6

now I want to publish few messages to kafka, included kafka-clients-1.0.0 in `war/web-inf/lib`

but its getting `NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer`.

Comment: Are there other libraries in the lib directory you're able to use? And Kafka 1.0 won't run on JDK 1.6 since it's compiled against Java 7

Comment: other jars inside lib are running fine, so you want me downgrade the version of kafka-clients?

Comment: Java 6 is EOL. You should be using at least Java 8, though 7 will work up to Kafka 2.0

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` usually happens when your project has conflict dependencies, for example 3rd and 4th versions of Spring framework. Check your dependencies and their transitive ones.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means the class which you are trying to run was not found in on your classpath. 
Solution: you need to add the class or .jar file which contains this class into the java classpath.